# Using @use 'sass:color' is making variables imported via additionalData unavailable in my Vue.js / Vite app

Tags: vue.js, sass, vite

I am using Vue.js with Vitest with the sass loader.

When I use `@use 'sass:color'` in an inline scss file or in a component, it seems to override variables which are set in `css.preprocessorOptions.scss.additionalData` in my `vite.config.ts` file.

The issue is reproduced here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-nk8yf5?file=src%2Fstyle%2Fsample.scss

For future reference, the setup is as follows:

**./src/style/vars.scss**

```
$sample-var: red;
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `@use "./src/style/vars.scss" as *;`,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

**./src/style/sample.scss**

```
@use 'sass:color';

.sample-style {
  color: $sample-var;
}
```

**Component**:

```
<script setup>

</script>

<template>
  <div class="sample-style">Hello sample style</div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import '../style/sample.scss';
</style>
```

With this code, I get `Undefined variable.` for the `$sample-var` in `sample.scss`.

However, if I comment out `@use 'sass:color';` it works as expected (I can access `$sample-var` within my component files.

What is going on here? How can I properly import `sass:color` in my component styles, while making a set of variables globally accessible using `additionalData` in vite.config.js? I'm interested in learning what the best practice is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scss code defined in `additionalData` gets prepended to the `<style>` tag of the component. So what the Sass compiler ends up processing is:

```scss
@use "./src/style/vars.scss" as *;
@import '../style/sample.scss';
```

When `sample.scss` does **not** include any `@use` statements, as per [the documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import):

> When Sass imports a file, that file is evaluated as though its contents appeared directly in place of the `@import`. Any mixins, functions, and variables from the imported file are made available, and all its CSS is included at the exact point where the `@import` was written.

That means that the above is evaluated similarly to:

```scss
@use "./src/style/vars.scss" as *;
.sample-style {
  color: $sample-var;
}
```

However, as per [the documentation on importing a module-system file](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import/#importing-a-module-system-file) (emphasis mine):

> When you import a file that contains `@use` rules, the importing file has access to all members (even private members) defined directly in that file, **but not any members from modules that file has loaded**.

`$sample-var` is a member from a module, and thus `sample.scss` does not have access to `$sample-var`.

Comment: Excellent, thanks this is clear and really helps. So sounds like the best solution is just to have both `@use 'sass:color';` and `@use "./src/style/vars.scss" as *;` in `./src/style/sample.scss`?

Comment: The solution I'd go for is to have both `@use 'sass:color';` and `@use "./src/style/vars.scss" as *;` in `./src/style/sample.scss`.